# htaccess Redirect old URLs with query string to new SEO URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know this is a usual question/problem, but I've spent a few hours looking for an answer and I've found too many different solutions which differs too much from each other. I'd like to know which is the "best" way (best practice) to accomplish that.

My htacces file looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www URLs to www-prefixed ones
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP ones
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirect URLs with trailing slashes to ones without it
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Now the last important step is required: redirect the old URLs like

`http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=abc` and `http://www.domain.com/?page=abc`

to the new ones:

`http://www.domain.com/abc`

I know I should probably check `{QUERY_STRING}` and put this redirect BEFORE the last line which rewrites the URLs, or maybe not? How to correctly write such a rule?

Comment: Are you sure you want to redirect this `http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=abc`, for example, to this `http://www.domain.com/abc` and not the other way around?

Comment: Yes, of course. The rewrite is already working, now I need to REDIRECT those old urls to the new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect `http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=abc and http://www.domain.com/?page=abc` to new ones use this additional rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I'd like to understand how it works and eventually be able to come up myself with a solution next time, could you explain me what it does and how, please?

Comment: Above rule is acting on `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable that has full URI with query string. `^[A-Z]{3,}` matches GET, PUT etc. `(?:index\.php)?` matches `index.php` optionally. and finally `\?page=([^\s]+)` matches your query string and groups page parameter's value in `%1` variable which is used in RewriteRule.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great use of RegEx and clever RewriteRule, I had no idea I could write it that way.